# Combine weekday and time in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, weekday

The data I have is data that increases or decreases by 1 at certain periods in time. There is a weekly pattern in the cumulated sum, and I would like to plot the pattern of multiple weeks on top of each other to see if the pattern stays the same per week.

I have added a column of weekdays, and a column with just the times. Is there any way I can join these in a single column, so I can cut the data per week and plot them all on the same x-axis?

For plotting just one week I used the following code (in Jupyter notebooks):

```
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 4)) 
plt.plot('event_time','total_occupied', data = mydata)
```

The event times are sometimes one minute apart and at other times they are 1 hour apart.

I hope I have explained the problem correctly, if not I will happily provide further explanation.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]? It is hard to understand what your data looks like and what your expected output is.